# How to delete a column of a csv in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am working with a csv file in a jupyter notebook, and I am wondering how to delete an entire column. When it is a normal csv file, I can click anywhere on the csv to convert it into a numbers file, and delete a column from there. In jupyter, the file is a strange format, without cells like a normal csv. Is there a way to delete a column still? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to delete a column from a CSV file using `pandas`.

It's **very** simple; the extra code is to provide context of what is in the CSV file before and after the change.

#### Display the contents of the CSV file:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())

col1,col2,col3,col4
0,item0,thing0,widget0
1,item1,thing1,widget1
2,item2,thing2,widget2
3,item3,thing3,widget3
4,item4,thing4,widget4
```

#### Read CSV into a DataFrame and delete a column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.drop(columns=['col2'], inplace=True)
```

#### Result:

```
 col1     col3     col4
0   0   thing0  widget0
1   1   thing1  widget1
2   2   thing2  widget2
3   3   thing3  widget3
4   4   thing4  widget4
```

#### Write the result back to a CSV file:

```
df.to_csv('test2.csv', index=False)
```

#### Display the contents of the new CSV file:

```
with open('test2.csv', 'r') as f:
print(f.read())

col1,col3,col4
0,thing0,widget0
1,thing1,widget1
2,thing2,widget2
3,thing3,widget3
4,thing4,widget4
```